# Accuracy requirement of GNU GCC math functions?

Tags: c, math, gcc, floating-point

I have tried in vain for several days to find the accuracy of Math functions(in math.h) of GNU GCC compiler. C99 standard says that the accuracy requirement of Math functions in math.h is implementation defined. I could not find any mention about this in the GNU GCC compiler manuals.
Does anyone have a answer to this ?

Comment: Is there a particular set of functions you are interested in? I'd guess the list of functions in math.h is fairly long.

Comment: I started this search looking for _pow()_ and _exp()_

Answer (score 10):

The `math.h` functions are part of the GNU C Library, not the GCC compiler.  Their accuracy is documented [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Errors-in-Math-Functions.html#Errors-in-Math-Functions), as part of the [GNU C Library manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/).

Comment: Thanks for the answer; I guess the '-'s in the table (1st link) mean unknown/untested, am I correct?

Comment: @user1200373 - Yes, I assume that the '-' means unknown or untested,  but I'm not positive.

Comment: Note that this only applies if you are using `gcc` with the GNU C Library, which is far from the only option.  Eg if you are using `gcc` on FreeBSD then you are instead using the FreeBSD C library; if you are using the `gcc` in MinGW then you are using the Microsoft C library, and so on.

Comment: The '-'s in the table mean those functions are accurate to within half an ULP.

Comment: @DavidHammen: That doesn't seem to be documented anywhere; it would be more reasonable to guess that `-` means the largest tested error is less than one ulp (which is a *vastly* weaker claim than saying the error is within half an ulp).

Comment: Beware: GCC may *not* call the Glibc function if it thinks it can do the job more efficiently inline. It will typically do this where the CPU has a specific instruction (or instructions) to do the operation. In that case the accuracy will depend on the processor implementation. Also, if the expression is constant it may evaluate it at compile time, not run time, in which case it will depend on the compilation environment, which might not match where it runs. GCC typically ensures the accuracy is quite good though. There's an option `-ffast-math` to enable "shortcuts" that reduce accuracy.

Answer (score 1):

The only safe thing to assume is that the '-' characters in the glibc math accuracy chart:

http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Errors-in-Math-Functions.html#Errors-in-Math-Functions

mean "not tested", given the lack of official documentation suggesting otherwise.

Comment: It's a table of *errors.* '-' therefore means no error; a value means an error of that magnitude. It isn't reasonable to assume that functions like `ciel()`, `exp(),` `fmod()`, etc. haven't been tested.

Comment: Then '0' (zero) would surely be more appropriate than the misleading '-', perhaps.

Answer (score 1):

The errors are indeed listed [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Errors-in-Math-Functions.html), but IMHO the assumption that "-" means "correctly rounded" (i.e. 1/2 *ulp*) is almost certainly refuted by the statement at the top of the page

> [T]he GNU C Library does not aim for correctly rounded results for
>   functions in the math library ... Instead, the goals for accuracy of
>   functions without fully specified results are as follows; some
>   functions have bugs meaning they do not meet these goals in all cases.
>   In future, the GNU C Library may provide some other correctly rounding
>   functions under the names such as crsin proposed for an extension to
>   ISO C.

After researching the source code a bit, I found what appears to be [the results of a ulp test](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=sysdeps/x86_64/fpu/libm-test-ulps;hb=HEAD) (for x86-64). It looks like, for the default rounding mode (round to nearest, ties go to even), they only explicitly test `double` when the *ulp* of `long double` (80 bit IEEE) is worse than `float`. The implicit assumption seems to be that `double` *can't* be worse than `long double`. For the directed rounding modes, they seem to always test both `float` and `double` explicitly.

There is some weirdness, though.

- There are no test results listed for `exp`.
- For `cos` and `tan`, they only test real/complex `long double`.